# Pentaho Geokettle: Convert Epoch time to human time

Tags: database, pentaho, epoch, pentaho-spoon, geokettle

I am currently working with Pentaho GeoKettle (or Spoon) and I am trying to import data into a database from a csv file. In the csv-file, there is a column which holds a timestamp in Epoch-format. But I have to import it to the database in the human timestamp(with timezone)-format: for example: 2017-06-01 13:10:12+00

How can this be achieved in geokettle?

Answer (score 1):

A date is a date and the same whatever the format you want to use to make it human readable or computer writable. In kettle, a column has a value (which is a byte value), a type (which maybe a date) and a format(which may be 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ', with Z for time zone).

So, if you read a timestamp as a integer in a coluimn named `myDate`, you need to convert it into a Date. And the easiest is to use a `Modified Javascript value` with a single line of code:

```
myDate = new Date(myDate)
```

and in the bottom table, put `myDate` as `Fieldname` with `Type` `date` and say Yes in the column `Replace in fieldset`.

Now that myDate has the right type, you set its format on the `Meta-data` tab of a `Select value` step. Select the format from the drop-down (and you can add a final Z for the final +0:00 if you want a Zulu time). You can also select the language and the time zone.